# JavaScript SlideDown On Mouse Hover Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code in which when a person hover on text it should slidedown div but its not working can someone please check and point whats the reason

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<div class="good_main">
<div class="more_save_box">
        <div class="top_wholesaleInquiry_button_20161213 more_save">
            Wholesale Inquiry
        </div>
        <div class="more_save_tips" style="display: none;">
            <span class="arrow_a"><i><i></i></i></span>
            <h3>Bulk Buy Discounts</h3>
            Order 3 or more and enjoy the savings. Bulk prices will be shown in the shopping cart.
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="1">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Qty (unit)</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                    <th>30</th>
                    <th>100</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="has">
                    <td>Price <span>US$</span></td>
                <td>12.99</td><td>12.53</td><td>12.36</td><td>12.21</td><td>12.04</td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <span class="top_wholesaleInquiry_button_20161213" id="more_save_tips_contact">Looking for more wholesale prices, <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/Contact-Us_hi558?products_id=975808">Wholesale Inquiry</a></span>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(".good_main .more_save_box").hover(
    function(){
        $(".good_main .more_save_tips").stop().slideDown(); 
    },
    function(){
        $(".good_main .more_save_tips").hide(); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in document ready statement, use mouseover/mouseout events

```js
  $(function(){
    $(".good_main .more_save_box").mouseover(function(){
            $(".good_main .more_save_tips").stop().slideDown(); 
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(".good_main .more_save_tips").hide(); 
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="good_main">
  <div class="more_save_box">
    <div class="top_wholesaleInquiry_button_20161213 more_save">
      Wholesale Inquiry
    </div>
    <div class="more_save_tips" style="display: none;">
      <span class="arrow_a"><i><i></i></i></span>
      <h3>Bulk Buy Discounts</h3>
      Order 3 or more and enjoy the savings. Bulk prices will be shown in the shopping cart.
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Qty (unit)</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>10</th>
            <th>30</th>
            <th>100</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="has">
            <td>Price <span>US$</span></td>
            <td>12.99</td>
            <td>12.53</td>
            <td>12.36</td>
            <td>12.21</td>
            <td>12.04</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <span class="top_wholesaleInquiry_button_20161213" id="more_save_tips_contact">Looking for more wholesale prices, <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/Contact-Us_hi558?products_id=975808">Wholesale Inquiry</a></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks and thanks to all those who have replied this platform has always been helpful for me in learning new things.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you put your `jQuery` code inside `document.ready` function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".good_main .more_save_box").hover(
    function(){
        $(".good_main .more_save_tips").stop().slideDown(); 
    },
    function(){
        $(".good_main .more_save_tips").hide(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when the jquery code is loaded when the `dom` is `ready`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".good_main .more_save_box").hover(
    function(){
        $(".good_main .more_save_tips").stop().slideDown(); 
    },
    function(){
        $(".good_main .more_save_tips").hide(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="good_main">
<div class="more_save_box">
        <div class="top_wholesaleInquiry_button_20161213 more_save">
            Wholesale Inquiry
        </div>
        <div class="more_save_tips" style="display: none;">
            <span class="arrow_a"><i><i></i></i></span>
            <h3>Bulk Buy Discounts</h3>
            Order 3 or more and enjoy the savings. Bulk prices will be shown in the shopping cart.
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="1">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <th>Qty (unit)</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                    <th>30</th>
                    <th>100</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="has">
                    <td>Price <span>US$</span></td>
                <td>12.99</td><td>12.53</td><td>12.36</td><td>12.21</td><td>12.04</td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <span class="top_wholesaleInquiry_button_20161213" id="more_save_tips_contact">Looking for more wholesale prices, <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="/Contact-Us_hi558?products_id=975808">Wholesale Inquiry</a></span>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```